# Пост запрос не видить сигнатуру freekassa, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Controller

```
public function makePayments(Request $request)
{
    $merchant_id = '****';
    $order_amount = $request->input('oa');
    $secret_word = '*********';
    $order_id = time();
    $currency = 'RUB';
    $sign = md5($merchant_id . ':' . $order_amount . ':' . $secret_word . ':' . $order_id . ':' . $currency);
    
    return view('cabinet.make-payment', compact('merchant_id', 'order_amount', 'order_id', 'sign', 'currency'));
    
}

    
public function handlePaymentNotification(Request $request)
{
    $merchant_id = '****';
    $merchant_secret = '*********';
    
    $sign = md5($merchant_id . ':' . $request->input('AMOUNT') . ':' . $merchant_secret . ':' . $request->input('MERCHANT_ORDER_ID'));
   
    print_r($sign);

    if ($sign != $request->input('SIGN')) {
        return response(' wrong sign', 400);
    }

    return response('YES');
}
```

Страница с формой

```
<form method='get' action='https://pay.freekassa.ru/'>
    @csrf
    <input type='hidden' name='m' value='{{ $merchant_id }}'>
    <input type="hidden" name="oa" value='{{ $order_amount }}'>
    <input type='hidden' name='o' value='{{ $order_id }}'>
    <input type='hidden' name='s' value='{{ $sign }}'>
    <input type='hidden' name='currency' value='{{ $currency }}'>
    <input type='hidden' name='i'>
    <input type='hidden' name='lang' value='ru'>
    <input type='submit' name='pay' value='Оплатить'>
</form>
```

Страница для пополнения

```
<span class="payments-pay">Pay</span>
<div class="payments">
    <form method='get' action='{{url('cabinet/make-payment') }}'>
        @csrf
        <input type='number' name='oa' value="">
        <input class="pay" type='submit' value="Пополнить">
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить данный вопрос помогите!
Нужно решить проблему ошибку подписи - ошибка в картинке.

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Какое отношение к данным формам имеет роут `payment-notification` и метод `handlePaymentNotification`?

Comment: Он принимает ответ post, URL ОПОВЕЩЕНИЯ с формы.

Comment: @Trocken вы дёргаете свой URL ОПОВЕЩЕНИЯ сами (вероятно для теста), так? Какой SIGN вы туда передаёте? На скриншоте не видно, но кажется никакого.